# How to wait for a Firebase retrieve value and only then exit the function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase query.

Because Firebase works asynchronously, the function continue to run without waiting for the Firebase retrieve value.

Is there a way to wait for the result from the Firebase query and only then to make the return from the function?

```
function CheckBuyingCondition(prefix) {

    var Res = "";

    var Current_Price_Open_ref = firebase.database().ref("dailyT/Current_Price_Open/" + nextDayTrading).orderByChild("Prefix").equalTo(prefix)
    Current_Price_Open_ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var val = childSnapshot.val();
                res = "" + val.Current_Price_Open;
            });
        }
        else {
            res = "NA";
        }
    });

    return res; // (Here I got res = "" instead of the correct value from Firebase query
}
```

Comment: Firebase queries are promises

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `async/await`:

```
async function checkBuyingCondition(prefix) {
  var res = '';

  var currentPriceOpenRef = firebase.database()
    .ref(`dailyT/currentPriceOpen/${nextDayTrading}`)
    .orderByChild('prefix')
    .equalTo(prefix);

  var snapshot = await currentPriceOpenRef.once('value');

  if(snapshot.exists()) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var val = childSnapshot.val();
      res = `${val.currentPriceOpen}`;
    });
  } else {
    res = 'NA';
  }

  return res;
}
```

Take note that this does not make your function synchronous at all, thus the `async` keyword at the beginning of your function declaration; it just makes your function look like one.

On the third line inside the function you'll notice the `await` keyword. This waits for your promise to resolve then returns the result which in your case, is the snapshot from Firebase. You can only use `await` inside `async` functions.

More reading: [JavaScript Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

You're proposing making the Firebase SDK asynchronous call into an synchronous call.  This is not a good idea, and to be honest, not even possible in JavaScript.  If you need to make a helper function that deals with Firebase APIs, that function should instead accept a callback function to be invoked when the work completes, or return a promise so that the caller of the function can decide what to do next.

[Read here to learn more about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CheckBuyingCondition(prefix) {

    var Res = "";

    var Current_Price_Open_ref = firebase.database().ref("dailyT/Current_Price_Open/" + nextDayTrading).orderByChild("Prefix").equalTo(prefix)
        return Current_Price_Open_ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var val = childSnapshot.val();

                res = "" + val.Current_Price_Open;
            });
            return res;
        }
        else {
            res = "NA";
        }
    });
}
```

Firebase queries are promises, so you because you can return the result from the promise and get it with another promise.

Comment: Thank You, How do I get the value that returned from the function in a good way? becuse now i got [object Promise]

Comment: Use .then(result){your code}
result variable is the value of res that you returned

Comment: Thank you again, I did it but now it makes the returned function to be asynchronous.

          CheckBuyingCondition(prefix).then(function(res) {
      console.log("res:"  + res);
  
   });
  
          console.log("It run this comment beafore the Promise returned");

Comment: What is the output of res, in the console log?

Comment: Now the outpot of res is the correct value !
but the next code after "res" runs parallel, 
What I need is that the next code will wait for "res" result first.